# How to run JAX-RS in Maven project of JAVA EE?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, netbeans

This is what I did on NetBeans.

New Project -> Maven -> Web Application

and gave my project name

And, created new RESTFUL Web services from patterns 
selected Simple Root Resource
Assigned path "foo"
and hit finish

And now, I tried to access it from browser as

```
localhost:8084/context/webresources/foo
```

And, it shows 404 resources not found error.

I checked if it works with non-maven based projects, and it does. Accessing the resource was possible on those but, not on maven based.

I must have missed something.

I also tried to see if it is accessible from netbeans by doing right-click on the RESTful Web Services and clicking TestResource Uri,
It shows error

Unable to open resource url.

```
the uri of the rest location
```

Make sure project has been deployed successfully and the server is running.

While both have been done!!

Comment: Possibly `<context>` is wrong. If you didn't change anything else, the default context root is the war name. The name will be `project-1.0-SNAPSHOT` (not just `project`). If you want to change it you can add `<finalName>project</finalName>` inside the `<build>` in the pom

Comment: it didn't work that way.

Comment: What did you do? Did you change the finalName? What server are you deploying to?

Comment: It works fine for me deploying to Glassfish

Comment: I am working on Tomcat.

Comment: The javaee-api dependency **is not** an implementation. It is pretty much API interfaces. If you run the app in a Java EE server, the server will have the implementation of the API. Tomcat is not a EE server and will have **no** implementation of the API. If you want to run in Tomcat, then you need a JAX-RS implementation on the classpath, like Jersey

Comment: Do this (1) New Project (2) Maven (3) Project from Archetype (4) Search "jersey-quickstart-webapp" (5) Select the "org.glassfish" (2.x) one. This will give you a running app you can run on Tomcat

Comment: Thanks. But, I downloaded standalone jersey repository from Maven depency on pom.xml. It worked out that way.